# converting arbortext xml to DITA or something that can be converted to DITA

Tags: xml, dita

Anyone know of shortcut method to convert arbortext xml to DITA XML. Maybe an xslt file that changes custom arbortext tags to equivalent dita tags. Maybe a script or program that converts to html first then I could use oxygen to convert to dita.

Comment: Can you clarify what "arbortext xml" is? Arbortext is an editor and the only "arbortext tags" that I can think of are the "Pub" processing instructions that Arbortext uses for processing.

Comment: Arbortext is a generic XML editor and can be configured to work with any XML content model (aka DTD/schema). In fact, Arbortext itself ships with DITA 1.2 XML support. You will need to be more specific about the current DTD you have authored your XML content to. Docbook? NLM? JATS? TEI? MILSPEC?

Comment: Ok, that explains things a little clearer for me since I have never used arbortext. The xml files I am dealing with include tags such as <Chapter.Title>Overview</Chapter.Title>
<Chapter.Desc>
<Normal.Para> from a Publication.dtd file. Must be custom dtd used by this company. This company is looking for someone to do remote work from home converting xml files created in Arbortext to DITA using oxygen. Not sure I want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an XSLT conversion and there might be a way to map it to DITA but the content model would probably be a very generic one as there probably is no typing information to go from that DTD to concept, task and reference. I'm sure there are folks who would be able to do the conversion without Arbortext as XML to XML is not difficult. Real hard conversions are Word to structured XML.